# How can one initiate a call in Linux?

Tags: linux, network-programming, sip, gstreamer, rtp

i am trying to implement a telephone service between **two Linux computers** using their in-built Mics and Speakers. I have managed to transmit Audio signals using **WLAN** over **IP** from one Linux computer to another using **Gstreamer Tool**.And it is Real time ( i used **RTP, UDP** )

In the whole Real-time-call story , this would only be the Media transfer level.

Now my question is how do i implement a signaling application i.e. it would try to connect to a destination IP and port and if it an **acknowledgment** is received the **Transport layer** (my Gstreamer Tool ) would start to work and send voice signals?

Comment: To start, you need a program that listens on a socket bound to an agreed-upon port.

Comment: @n.m. i have two Gstreamer Pipelines, one is the sender and the other is the receiver. in the receiver listening on a UDP port has been designed. what i need is a way to signal the initiation of these two pipelines

Comment: You need to send some agreed-upon message to said port.

Comment: @n.m. what do you mean by agreed upon? the two parties have no logical connections whatsoever.

Comment: You cannot talk if you have no common language with the other party. Gstreamer protocol is one such language. Both parties have agreed to use it. Now you need to invent a call initiation protocol, and have both parties agree to it. Good luck.

Comment: @n.m. there is SIP protocol which is used to initiate a call between two parties and i have read in Internet that the media layer of the call can be implemented by Gstreamer media streams, i just don't know how